# Create flatten dates sequence in Google Sheets in one column (without using MACRO FUNCTIONS)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, arraylist, sequence, flatten

I have a table in Google Sheets with the following structure:

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| Start Date 1 | End Date 1 |
| Start Date 2 | End Date 2 |
| Start Date 3 | End Date 3 |

I'm using the following formula:

`IFERROR(FLATTEN( SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(D2,E2,"D"), 1, D2, 1), SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(D3,E3,"D"), 1, D3, 1), SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(D4,E4,"D"), 1, D4, 1), SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(D5,E5,"D"), 1, D5, 1) ),"")`

This formula is working fine for what I want as a result (all the dates between start and end date in one single column).

However, it's not very efficient in the sense that for every row that is added to the table I need to add another SEQUENCE function to my formula.

Is there a way to do this automation with only one SEQUENCE function?

The idea would be something like this:

`IFERROR(FLATTEN( SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(D2:D,E2:E,"D"), 1, D2:D, 1)),"")`

But it just doesn't work. I was wondering if I could do this without requesting any MACROS also.

I tried with the following: `SEQUENCE( SUM( DATEDIF(D2:D,E2:E,"D") ) , 1 ,SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(D2:D,E2:E,"D"), 1, D2:D, 1),1)`

and also with `ArrayFormula(iferror(if(A2:A="",,transpose(split(concatenate(rept(A2:A&",",1+networkdays(A2:A,B2:B))),",")))))`

I was expecting to have a sequence of all the dates between the start date and the end date in one single column, in a way that after the end date, the next row would have the following start date, and so on.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=query(reduce(,sequence(counta(A2:A)),lambda(a,c,{a;SEQUENCE(index(map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(x,y,if(x="",,days(y,x)+1))),c),1,index(A2:A,c),1)})),"offset 1",0)
```

- `Format` the output column to needed date styling

[image]